# Truly-handrwriting monospaced font

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

Is there a truly-handrwriting monospaced font? Does it exist at all?

I know there is a [*Marista*](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/marista-font-zephyris) by Zephyris, but it is not what I really looking for. It still looks as a font produced by a typewriter, whereas I look for something produced by longhand, for example, something like [*The Girl Next Door*](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/The+Girl+Next+Door) or [*Gaegu*](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Gaegu).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Handwriting" and "monospaced" seem in direct opposition to me. Handwriting is *never* monospaced. And monospacing will *immediately* remove any connotation of "handwriting" and just appear to be a scribble font.

Comment: Scott, I do understand it. But what if you have to write a snippet of code by hand and I give you a sheet of paper and a pencil?

Comment: It won't be monospaced.

Comment: Are you sure? :-) You still need to keep alignment. And for this reason, you will need to write it in such a way that each letter and each punctuation mark will take it's own invisible box, and each box must be the same size. (It will be much easier if you will write in a math exercise book.)

Comment: I disagree.. handwritten code has no need to align vertically. Manual indentations will clearly show nesting. Monospacing is an exclusive aspect of typeset code to make it easier to determine nesting given the inherent grid all digital materials must use for display. And math equations may align vertically because math may be read *top down* at times. Code isn't read top down that I'm aware of. Anyway.. good luck in your hunt.. perhaps I've overlooked a font out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like [some of the fonts from Tabular Type Foundry](https://fonts.ilovetypography.com/fonts/tabular-type-foundry), by Toshi Omagari. (Full disclosure: I've met him, he's a really nice guy.) They're monospaced but with a lot of script character.

Comment: Copilot, you just can't imagine how Toshi's _Tabulamore Script_ is helpful for me. It seems it is the final step to break my OCD, which affects any work with typed text, and which poisoned my life for about 15 years.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, I found such a font!

It is [Yomogi](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Yomogi) by Satsuyako.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 Glad you sorted it. But c'mon, that doesn't look like "truly handwriting" `:)` And you may want to turn off ligatures.. the FL and FF ligatures stood out to me `:)`

Comment: If anyone aware of other fonts like Yomogi or Tabulamore Script, please let me know! `:)`